# Automatic email

Tags: php, yii

I am a new user of Yii framwork, and I have implement YiiMail, which works well. But now I want to send mails automatically at the end of each month, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps are as follows:

1. **Set up a crontab** on your server, that will run a PHP command.
   On Windows you can set a scheduled task which will run `<yourdir>/protected/yiic-dev.bat` with the proper commands to run (take a look at [CConsoleCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand)), which will send the emails.
   On the production server, you do the same but with `php <yourdir>/protected/yiic.php` as the cron with the command to run as argument, which will do the same but on a Linux environment (if it's a Windows server, just make a scheduled command for `<yourdir>/protected/yiic.bat` and the proper arguments)
2. **Send the emails** in the corresponding action, by using the mail class (see the documentation for [YiiMailer](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/#hh4))

If there are further problems and you run into more specific issues you can't work around, I suggest you make new questions for them.

Comment: Thank you for your rapidity, for now I'm in development phase, for an intern project in PhP, and I am using WAMP on my own computer. Crontab is only on Linux/Unix OS ? The company I work for have is own server, and I still don't know if I will use their or another hosting type.

Comment: And I have never used scheduled task, is it difficult ? I can find easily doc on it no ?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task It's quite easy, just point the task to hit a `.php` file (That's on a web server), which will run at a given time - or a `.bat` file as written above as sorry for missing that!

Comment: Thank you for that. I will implement it ASAP.